# NullPointerException on Image.createImage(path)

Tags: ios, codenameone, picker

This code give me a `NullPointerException` on `Image.createImage(path)` in the for cycle.
How is it possible?

I use an array for name, one for path and an `ArrayList` for buttons.

```
private final String[] IMG_MENU = {"/timbratura.png", "/archivio.png", "/nota_spese.png"};
private final String[] LABEL_BOTTONI_HOME = {"Timbratura", "Archivio", "Nota spese"};
private ArrayList<Button> bottoni = new ArrayList<>();
```

I create some buttons, set icon as image generated and add it to an `ArrayList`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < LABEL_BOTTONI_HOME.length; i++) {
  Button b = new Button(LABEL_BOTTONI_HOME[i]);

  try {
      Image im = Image.createImage(IMG_MENU[i]);
      im = im.scaled(screen_width/100*20, screen_width/100*20);
      b.setIcon(im);        
  } catch (IOException ex) {
      Log.e(ex);
  }

  bottoni.add(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the images are actually there (the 'src' directory and eventually in the jar) and have the exact same case sensitive name. I would strongly suggest adding the images to the resource file and using `getImage` on the theme to get them from there as that's a more portable approach.